# Is it legal for my app to "crawl" websites and use their information?

Tags: android, web-crawler

I have an idea for an app but I don't know if it would be legal to implement it. Can I "crawl" information my app would use from assorted websites? For the purposes of this question, "crawl" means parsing out information on a website and storing it in my own database. This way, I would have my own server with all the information I need for my application to run.

I think there is nothing illegal about crawling RSS feeds. But what if the website I want information from doesn't have an RSS feed? Is it legal to crawl that website?

Comment: Depends on the site. Contact the admins/company and ask for permission or further information. Read the TOS. There is no general answer. Also this is OT on stackoverflow. It's a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: I think it is a "good to know" question for other programmers as well, isnt it? I know, i dont want to know how to do it but i think to know the legality of stuff like this is also very important for programmers, isnt it?

Comment: As said, there is no definitive answer. This depends on too many factors to have a question here that's helpful to everyone. E.g. your country, the country of the website/company, the Terms of Use, and so on. Ask all you want, here is my normal disclaimer: What people tell you here is based on their personal opinion and common sense. Laws are not based on common sense at times and differ across countries. *"User XYZ on StackOverflow said it's ok"* does not save you in court. **Want legal advice? Ask a lawyer**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely not, you should ask the owner of the site, if you can extract the content of his website. Very often there is even information for the reserved rights at the bottom of a given site, but the lack of such, doesn't give you a permission for taking the content. It is a good idea to provide a link, to the source of your content. In this way there shouldn't be problems with the website owner.